# Dipl. Math requirements

Tags: mathematics, degree, germany

I would like to know what are the (academic) requirements (in general) of a **Dipl. Math.**?

What Dipl. math. Is good for (in math Academia)? More general what is a Dipl. Math.?

(Some reference for cover letters for Dipl. Math.)

Comment: What does "Dipl" stand for? I'm assuming "Diploma"?

Comment: It depends on where you go to school.

Comment: Which country are you asking about?

Comment: I refer after earning a bachelor. Germany, USA or Uk.

Comment: Dipl. Math isn't a degree that you'll see being granted in the US.  I also don't think that you'll find it in the UK.

Comment: Nor in Germany anymore.

Comment: At least in the U.S., you will find degree requirements posted clearly on the department's website.

Answer (score 4):

*Dipl.-Math.* stands for *Diplom-Mathematiker.* It is a [German academic degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplom) and equivalent to a master’s degree.
Before Germany adopted the bachelor/master system, a *Diplom* (diploma) was awarded to students after finishing about five years of study and writing a thesis.
Almost all German universities now award bachelor’s and master’s degrees, but at some universities, students can choose to have their degree called *Diplom* after completing a master’s program.

Comment: Sounds like a _Diplom_ would be roughly equivalent to an [accelerated Master's](http://study.com/articles/Accelerated_Masters_Degree_Programs_How_Do_They_Work.html) in the US, which is a 5-year Bachelor's+Master's program.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be country specific. For example: in India, such a degree never existed. Rather, there is something equivalent such as "Master of Philosophy" or "M.Phil." for short. You could consider it as a "Pre-PhD" degree. It is mostly for 1 year, but there is no course and mostly full of research (though it again varies from universities to universities). Note that it is not mandatory to have an M.Phil. degree for Ph.D. admission. For M.Phil., the requirement is that the student must have a Master of Science (M.Sc.) degree.

For Germany and other countries, this being already answered.

Answer (score -1):

A diploma of mathematics is about equivalent to a Master in mathematics. It permits you to write a dissertation in mathematics.

Comment: can you add a country name?